# how to show only first 200 characters of a Post in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
<div class="panel-body">@Html.Raw(item.PostContent.Substring(0, 200))</div>
```

The above code produces error!, While when I hover mouse over `item.PostContent` it tells me that it is String!

while this code:

```
<div class="panel-body">@Html.Raw(item.PostContent)</div>
```

works fine and shows the whole post content!
What should I do to fix this?
I want to get the first 200 characters of a post and show them as an excerpt.

Comment: The error probably occurs on strings that are shorter than 200 characters. Check the string length before calling `Substring()`

Comment: *The above code produces error*.. can you post anything else?  What is the error?  The more you provide, the more we can help

Comment: I need to first get the plain text from html source in order not to mess the closing div tag! any simple way?

Comment: @user2548663, You are going to have to parse the content in the action first to get he content you want and then truncate as needed. Don't add too much complexity to the view.

Answer (score 3):

Something like below might be useful.

```
public static class HtmlPostExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString Post(this HtmlHelper helper, string postContent)
    {
        string postStr = postContent;
        if (postStr.Length > 200)
        {
               postStr = postStr.Substring(0, 200);    
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(postStr);
    }
}
```

Can be used as

```
@Html.Post(item.PostContent)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.PostContent) && item.PostContent.Length > 200)
{
  <span>@Html.Raw(item.PostContent.Substring(0, 200))</span>
}
else
{
  <span>@Html.Raw(item.PostContent)</span>
}
```

Comment: if the `PostContent` is **NOT** null and `PostContent`'s length is greater than 0?  So what you're saying with that logic, is that *if* the `PostContent` has a length of `1`, then it will not throw error when it reaches `<span>@Html.Raw(item.PostContent.Substring(0, 200))</span>`?  I think the issue deals with the `SubString` part where `PostContent` isn't `200` characters in length.

Comment: No need to apologize.  my comment was to simply allow you to check your logic.  A friendly check up! Good job on fixing it!

Answer (score 1):

Check if length is greater than 200 and truncate otherwise just use the length

```
<div class="panel-body">@Html.Raw(item.PostContent.Substring(0, item.PostContent.Length > 200 ? 200 : item.PostContent.Length))</div>
```

If possible you should do that in the action method before passing it on to the view. It would make the razor code/markup a lot cleaner. It can be done when projecting the model(s) [think LINQ]

> Post contents are in html. Therefore first I need to get the plain
>   text of that html source then get the first 200 characters. Any
>   solutions?

You are going to have to parse the content in the action first to get the content you want and then truncate as needed. Don't add too much complexity to the view.

You can use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)( [NuGet HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.9.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) ) to parse the content and extract the plain test of that html to then get the first 200 characters

```
var html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(item.PostContent);
var root = html.DocumentNode;
var postContent = root.InnerText;
var postLength = postContent.Length;
var truncatedContent = postContent.Substring(0, postLength > 200 ? 200 : postLength);
```

Again, this should be done before sending items to the View.